# How to enable, disable and reload systemd units and services for all users?

Tags: systemd

I'm writing a software package that includes a systemd unit. After installation its unit must be enabled for all users, and after removal it must be disabled.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [discussion](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12770) to implement this as "daemon-reexec" on user mode.

Meanwhile this is what works:

```
#! /bin/bash

Service="foo"


post_install () {
    if [[ "$(whoami)" == "root" ]]; then
        systemctl --user --global enable "${Service}"
        CommandForAllUsers systemctl --user start "${Service}"
    fi
}


pre_remove () {
    if [[ "$(whoami)" == "root" ]]; then
        CommandForAllUsers systemctl --user stop "${Service}"
        systemctl --user --global disable "${Service}"
    fi
}


post_remove () {
    if [[ "$(whoami)" == "root" ]]; then
        CommandForAllUsers systemctl --user daemon-reload
    fi
}


CommandAsUser () {
    local user="${1}"
    local command="${*:2}"

    local userId="$(id --user "${user}")"
    local bus="unix:path=/run/user/${userId}/bus"
    local sudoAsUser="sudo -u ${user} DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=${bus}"
    
    ${sudoAsUser} ${command}
}


CommandForAllUsers () {
    local command="${*}"
    local users; readarray -t users <<< "$(loginctl --no-legend list-users | awk '{print $2;}')"
    
    for user in "${users[@]}"; do
        CommandAsUser "${user}" "${command}"
    done
}
```